# How does "He does not faint or grow weary" fit against "he was asleep"?

Tags: contradiction

**Isaiah 40:28** all ESV.

> "Have you not known? Have you not heard? The LORD is the everlasting God, the Creator of the ends of the earth. He does not faint or grow weary; his understanding is unsearchable."

**John 1:10**

> "He was in the world , and the world was made was made through him, yet the world did not know him."

**Matthew 8:24**

> "And behold, there arose a great storm on the sea, so that the boat was being swamped by the waves: but he was asleep."

The world was made by him who was in the world. At one time when he was in the world he was asleep in a boat.

The Creator will not grow tired or weary. Jesus was creator of the world and is asleep.

Comment: The Chalcedonian answer is that the person of the Son created the universe in his divine  nature, and slept in his incarnate human nature. But this is a theological conclusion, and not something you can deduce just from those three passages alone.

Comment: The One who came in humanity was subject to the nature of humanity. He ate, he drank, he wept, he was weary, he was grieved, he suffered, his  blood was shed, he died. . . . . And he slept. There is absolutely _nothing_ to 'reconcile' here. Absolutely nothing. A very, very, rare down-vote for C.Stroud. Of God it is said, "His eyelids try the children of men" when he makes himself unavailable.

Comment: @Nigel Thanks. I was thinking "how" do these fit together; how one might present that fitting together, rather than suggest that that might be impossible.

Comment: I think this is a good question and have upvoted it.

Comment: To not faint or grow weary would apply to Jesus’ mission, not to his daily personal needs.

Comment: @curiousdannii... Not that I want this question closed, but I'm confused as to why you apparently think it does not call for an answer based on systematic theology.

Comment: @Dan I think it probably should be closed. But sometimes I like for the community to vote too rather than immediately closing questions just by myself.

Comment: @Dan Fefferman Does my comment to mrall below make any difference?

Comment: @Constantthin I agree. The "Son of Man " did not grow weary of his mission but physically tired in his mission.

Answer (score 1):

It is true that the NT presents Jesus as, on one hand:

- Creator of all things, Heb 1:2, 10, John 1:3, 10, Col 1:16
- Sustainer of all the universe, Col 1:17, and thus has unlimited power
- Commander of nature, Matt 8:27, Mark 4:41, Luke 8:25

... but on the other hand, became tired, hungry and thirsty, John 4:6, Matt 8:24, 21:18, Mark 11:12, etc.

To understand this dichotomy, is to understand the incarnation and the mysterious combination of human with the divine - it is beyond understanding.  Indeed, Jesus even claimed that, Like God the Father, Jesus is constantly working, presumably to uphold the universe, as per John 5:17.

We see the same "problem" with Jesus death and resurrection.  We note that the NT says that Jesus raised Himself from the dead, •   John 2:19-21 and 10:17, 18 (see appendix below).  If this is true, how did Jesus die?

Again, to understand God fully is to be God which is not a human privilege.  Some things must be accepted by faith.

**APPENDIX - Jesus' Resurrection**

Who raised Jesus from the grave.  The NT presents some interesting data:

- Acts 2:24, 3:15, 4:10, 5:30, 10:40, 13:30, 17:31, Rom 4:24, 1 Cor 15:15, Col 2:20, Heb 13:20, 1 Peter 1:3, 1 Thess 1:10 simply say that “God” raised Jesus without specifying any specific member of the Godhead
- Rom 6:4, Gal 1:1, Eph 1:17-20 say that the Father raised Jesus from the dead.
- Rom 1:4 & 8:11, 1 Peter 3:18 say that the Holy Spirit raised Jesus from the dead (see also 2 Cor 3:6).
- John 2:19-21 and 10:17, 18 both say that Jesus resurrected Himself.  Further, John 1:4 & 5:26 says that the Son has “life in Himself”, that is, is not dependent on the Father for His existence.  Compare 1 John 5:11 & 1:1, 2. [Note the Geneva Bible’s comment in Matt 28:1, “Christ, having routed death in the tomb, rises by his own power, as the angel immediately witnesses.”]

Answer (score 0):

Fainting and sleeping are two different things.

"**Fainting**, or passing out, is a temporary loss of consciousness from a sudden decrease of blood flow to your brain" from google.

"**Sleep** is a state of reduced mental and physical activity in which consciousness is altered and sensory activity is inhibited to a certain extent." wikipedia

Sleep involves consciousness, fainting does not.

Growing weary and sleeping are two different things.

"**weary**"

"feeling or showing tiredness,
especially as a result of excessive exertion or lack of sleep"
from googles dictionary.

And so growing weary involves lack of sleep or over exertion.

God is holding all the atoms of creation together.
Even as He slept in that boat,
all atoms remained intact and together.

Comment: Can you show in what ways these words are different?

Comment: Would you say that Jesus did not faint [Isaiah 40:29-31] because he waited on the LORD; he prayed. His soul was not weary [they shall run and not be weary] of spiritual battle, but his body was weary. "they shall walk and not faint" even those that "walk" [walk with the LORD] 24 hours a day  sleep at night.

Comment: Sleep is normal "they shall walk and not pass out"  if we are being specific. Yes Jesus was never weary of the spiritual battle, neither did He physically get weary, He got proper sleep and did not suffer from lack of sleep or over exertion.

Comment: I am using ESV. What version are you quoting please?

Comment: I'm plugging in the definition of the word faint, it means pass out, not sleep.

Comment: If you google "Isaiah 40:29 Hebrew" you can click on Hebrew word and get Brown-Driver-Briggs Bible definition of a Hebrew word. ie: "Faint"- weak of mind or spirit. Ordinary dictionaries do not give Hebrew colours/nuances.